# how do I control compiling behavior depending on hostname?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am sharing my Qt C++ development folders over nfs, to several hosts which have different CPUs, and I'd like to configure my project `.pro` file to make statements therein conditional on on the hostname?

For instance. In my `.pro` file I'd like to set:

```
If HOSTNAME=hydra
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Ofast -march=broadwell
else if HOSTNAME=wolfpack
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Ofast -march=haswell
```

Is this possible? and if yes, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: [`HOSTNAME = $$system(hostname)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command-mode-stsvar), then use `HOSTNAME` variable as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing this because it will making debugging your builds annoying in the long run, but:

```
equals(QMAKE_HOST.name, "hydra"): QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Ofast -march=broadwell
equals(QMAKE_HOST.name, "wolfpack"): QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Ofast -march=haswell
```